# Import comments from Facebook plugin to Disqus

Tags: facebook, import, comments, export, transfer

how can I transfer comments from Facebook comment plugin to Disqus?

Please keep in mind that my knowledge in scripts are very limited.

Answer (score 2):

Disqus automatically queries your FB page for comments. Most Facebook Comment plugins also query FB for comments posted there.

All you should need to do is find your Facebook App ID in the Facebook Comments plugin and then input this into your Disqus admin panel under Settings > Advanced > Facebook App ID. Your FB comments should automagically appear in Disqus.

Comment: Yes. Most Facebook comment plugins store their comments on Facebook, not in Wordpress. You need to create a Facebook app to connect Disqus to Facebook so it can read your comments there. Create one at https://developers.facebook.com/apps. Your FB App ID will is a 10+ digit number.

Comment: That App ID is the Facebook Comments app. You'll need to create your own. Perhaps this topic is better raised at http://disqus.com/support/

Comment: Also I tried this, but not worked

Answer (score -1):

Landed here looking for a solution, but found a solution from another blog. Sharing it here, so others might find it useful. This plugin solves the problem - http://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-facebook-comments/

SEO Facebook Comments embeds a Facebook Comment Form on your blog and also looks at each of your blog posts searching for Facebook Comments already posted and adds them to your WP database and once all FB comments are migrated to WP database it can be easily be imported to Disqus.